# SSIS Lookup to Excel file causes export to excel destination to fail

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel

I have an SSIS package that is all tested and working fine except for one part. When I try to export data to an Excel file that was previously used in a Lookup function, it returns this error:

[Excel Destination 1 [3340]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E09.

I have tried copying the file and then exporting the data to the copy and it works fine - it only fails when exporting to the same file used in the lookup. I have a feeling that the Lookup function uses the OLE DB connection that I've created for it and leaves it open, so that when the Excel Connection Manager tries to access the file to write on it, it is denied.

I've tried altering the OLE DB connection to the Excel file to be read-only, and to use full cache and no cache on the Lookup, but none of this has helped. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You are trying to use an Excel file as the destination *and* as the source for a lookup?

Comment: Yes. What I am trying to accomplish by this is to check if the database table has records that the excel file does not (by using the lookup function) and then to add any records that are missing to the excel file. So to clarify - the Lookup function takes dataflow from a database connection, compares it to an Excel table, then takes the unmatched rows and provides them to an Excel Destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe your assumption is correct, SSIS is taking an exclusive lock on the Excel file when it opens and isn't sharing that lock with itself. A quick rework would be to add a second SSIS package. This one populates a Cache Connection Manager with all of the Excel data. Persist the cache file to disk

Then in your existing SSIS package, change the Lookup to use the cache file instead of Excel directly. Now the only lock taken should be for the Excel Destination.

You then would need to make your invocation pattern

1. RunNewCachePackage
2. RunNormalPackage

Comment: This is a great idea. I was able to create a second data flow within the same package to create the cache; structuring it in this way does not result in a lock issue.